# How to remove only entities saved to store from Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm trying to build a caching system for a feed reading application. The idea is each time a new feed is successfully pulled, remove all stored entities in Core Data, and store the first twenty items of the feed (this is used as an offline cache).

The issue I'm running into is my managed object context may have hundreds of items in it when a pull to refresh is performed. I'd like to keep those items in the context while removing any stored items from Core Data and then store the twenty items returned from the refresh call.

For what it's worth, I'm using Magical Record. I've tried looking around for this solution, but either I'm using the wrong keywords or the information is hard to find.

I'm not sure what code to show exactly, but here's the handling of the feed call:

```
for (id dict in feedArray){
    WFeedItem *item = [WFeedItem feedItemWithAttributes:[dict dictionaryByReplacingNullsWithBlanks] inManagedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]];
    [parsedArray addObject:item];
}
```

This gets passed back from the subclassed HTTPClient it's defined in to a view controller that has called it. Bear in mind, this all works fine, it's all a matter of deleting stored items while retaining everything I've gathered during this session in the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a different context for importing and storing the new records. Your original object context can remain as it is.

Comment: Can I use a different context to retrieve only items already saved in the store as well? The problem I'm having when saving is that I need to remove what's already there without affecting the NSManagedObjects from the session. It's likely some of the new items from a feed call will already exist in the store, but I need to make sure the store always has the twenty most recent items...not sure if I'm explaining it well enough.

Comment: This is sort of what I wound up doing. Basically I didn't want one context to see what was stored, essentially, but since that couldn't happen I just my first twenty items to my default moc and saved it, then put the rest of my objects in a nil moc.